# Autologout on browser close

Tags: 7, sessions

I need to log out users when the browser session is closed and users are visiting a Drupal 7 site.

I tried to modify the lines on the settings.php which calls `ini_set()` for session values, but it seems this solution works with Drupal 6, but not with Drupal 7.

Is there a way to solve it in Drupal 7?

Comment: The cookie settings for Drupal 7 and Drupal 6 are slightly different (or slightly similar, as you prefer to see it). An approach could be using the [Automated logout](https://drupal.org/project/autologout) module.

Comment: I've tried to modify ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0); in settings.php, cleared cache but when i close the browser and reopen it, i'm automatically reconnected.

Comment: I didn't try this module, but the op in the link I shared mentions the [Automated logout project](https://drupal.org/project/autologout), maybe it is helpful for you.

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers.

Comment: Thanks Molot, I didnt know where to add it. Is it preferred to edit my answer with the extra link?